# SyntaxError when calling a .py script when I release the ImageButton

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a beginner at coding, currently I'm developing an app. Within that app I have an ImageButton, when I release it calls a .py script. However, for some reason it keeps giving me a SytanxError, even though (to my understanding) there's no SyntaxError.

The following is what I have in my main.py:

```
    def run_test(self):
        os.system("python externalconnection.py")
```

And the following is the code written in externalconnection.py:

```
import asyncio
from bleak import BleakClient

address = "#######"
rw_characteristic = '######'

async def connect(address):
    async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
        await client.get_services()
        value = await client.read_gatt_char(rw_characteristic)
        print("Pre-Write Value: {0}".format(value))
        await client.write_gatt_char(rw_characteristic, bytearray([0x01]), response=True)
        value = await client.read_gatt_char(rw_characteristic)
        print("Post-Write Value: {0}".format(value))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(connect(address))
```

And below is the error I get:

```
File "externalconnection.py", line 7
    async def connect(address):
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Also in case you wonder, the externalconnection.py is running just fine and does what I need, if I run it by itself on a separate project from the app.

Any help that I can get will be very much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is the error you would get if running this code under a Python version that doesn't yet have the `async def` syntax, such as Python 2.7.18.

Make sure the `python` executable you're resolving is what you think it is, and is a Python version that supports this syntax.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I'm currently using Python 3.9. Would there be any other way you could recommend that would work?

Comment: You clearly _intend_ to use Python 3.9, what I'm saying is that I don't think you actually are.

Comment: You could test this by e.g. replacing your os.system call with `"python -c "import sys;print(sys.version_info)"` and reading the result.